# Overriding non dataclass attribute with dataclass subclass causes attribute error

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Given the following datamodel

```
from typing import List    

class A:
    a: List[int] = []

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b: str, a: List[int] = []):
        self.b = b
        self.a = a
```

**Facts**

- It is gospel that `A` cannot be a `dataclass` (this would render the issue trivial)
- We want to inherit `A` via `B`
- We do not want to be able to set parameter `a` at instantiation of `A`
- We want to be able to set parameter `a` at instantiation of `B`

The following I would have assumed to work was

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class A:
    a: List[int] = []

@dataclass
class B(A):
    b: str
    a: List[int]
```

Correcting for the error `ValueError: mutable default <class 'list'> for field babies is not allowed: use default_factory` I get

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class A:
    a: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)

@dataclass
class B(A):
    b: str
    a: List[int]
```

but this yields the following error `AttributeError: a`

If I use an integer type for `a` instead, the following works, indicating that in theory what I am doing is ok, but I am expressing it incorrectly:

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

class A:
    a: int = 1

@dataclass
class B(A):
    b: str
    a: int
```

What am I doing wrong here ? How do I get this to work with `a` as an empty list in `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quoting the snippet from the `dataclasses` module that raises the error (function `_process_class`):

```
    # If the class attribute (which is the default value for this
    # field) exists and is of type 'Field', replace it with the
    # real default.  This is so that normal class introspection
    # sees a real default value, not a Field.
    if isinstance(getattr(cls, f.name, None), Field): 
        if f.default is MISSING:
            # If there's no default, delete the class attribute.
            # This happens if we specify field(repr=False), for
            # example (that is, we specified a field object, but
            # no default value).  Also if we're using a default 
            # factory.  The class attribute should not be set at
            # all in the post-processed class.
            delattr(cls, f.name) 
        else:   
            setattr(cls, f.name, f.default)
```

I think the comments show that the implementation does not expect that it has to process an inherited attribute. I think that implies that only processed attributes can be inherited, i.e. they must come from base dataclasses.

Comment: this seems to imply that the integer example is unintended behavior? I noticed that replacing with a default field value also breaks the integer example as the snippet above suggests

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane The important difference is that integer example does not use  a `Field`. From my personal point of view, the `dataclass` is a code generator (related video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw) and the way you are using is outside of its specification making the results undefined (that's fine for learning). The author of `dataclasses` is a SO user and he might give an "authoritative" answer.